# Google plus share using dynamic content not working

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I am working vehicle tracking website, here I have to share some dynamic content in google plus share that is as prefilled text. Issue is the content I am sharing in google plus is shared,when first time I click google plus share, after the content get refresh automatically one minute once through ajax, the prefill text content getting updated, but i click share button in google plus share window the content not getting posted to anyone.

Here is the sample code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Share Demo: Deferred execution with language code</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js"></script>
    <div id ="sharePost" action="share">Share</div>
<script>
function add(){
   var options = {
        contenturl: 'https://plus.google.com/pages/',
        contentdeeplinkid: '/pages',
        clientid: 'xxx',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        prefilltext: 'Hai happy friday'+Math.random(),
        calltoactionlabel: 'CREATE',
        calltoactionurl: 'http://plus.google.com/pages/create',
        calltoactiondeeplinkid: '/pages/create'
      };
      // Call the render method when appropriate within your app to display
      // the button.
      gapi.interactivepost.render('sharePost', options);
}

       setInterval(function(){
         add();
       },2000);

      add();
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can able to share interactive post using java script render method.The main point we need to noted is, we need to use same url for contenturl and calltoactionurl.

```
<html>
      <head>
        <title>Share Demo: Deferred execution with language code</title>
        <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com" />
      </head>
      <body>
      <script>
      window.___gcfg = {
                lang: 'en-US',
                parsetags: 'explicit'
              };
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
        <div id ="sharePost">Share</div>
     <script>
         (function() {
               var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
               po.src = 'http://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
               var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
             })();
         var options = {
                    contenturl: 'http://www.google.com',
                    contentdeeplinkid: '/pages',
                    clientid: 'xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                    cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
                    prefilltext: 'Hai happy friday',
                    calltoactionlabel: 'INVITE',
                    calltoactionurl: 'http://www.google.com'
                  };
                  // Call the render method when appropriate within your app to display
                  // the button.
                  gapi.interactivepost.render('sharePost', options);

          </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```